# Find my mistake: Conditional probability

Tags: probability

A box contains 5 balls numbered 1-5.

Two balls are drawn randomly.
Calculate the probability of selecting balls numbered 1 and 2.

Answer via counting: 1/5C2

Attempt with conditional probability:

A= ball numbered 1 drawn
B= ball numbered 2 drawn

P(draw 1 and 2)=P(A and B)=P(A)P(B|A)=(1/5)(1/4).

My calculation: Given A the updated sample space is:
{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5}

So P(B|A)= 1/4.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second calculation gives the probability of drawing ball 1 first and then ball 2. Your first calculation gives the probability of drawing the two balls in either order.

If you want the second calculation to allow either order, then $P(A)$ should be $\frac25$, not $\frac15$.

Comment: Yes, the event A could be a 1 on either the first or second  draw. 
Thanks.